# Deploy multiple wars to multiple remote containers through Jenkins job

Tags: deployment, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

Hi I'm using Jenkins to build and deploy to remote container. As of now my maven job build 5 webapps through one parent pom and deploy all wars into one remote container.

As of now I'm using deploy plugin which is allowing to deploy a war to single remote container.

Now I wanted to put each war into a different remote container. Please let me know any plugins available or any scripts to use to specify where to deploy each war file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write an ant script for this purpose. Tomcat manager plugin can be controlled through Ant, so you can write five different tasks for your 5 different servers. You can add this ant script as a post build task.

Thanks
Param